# What does this {} means after parameter in verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

```
module test #(parameter WIDTH = 4) (output wire [WIDTH-1:0] result, input wire input );
// synopsys template
assign result = {WIDTH{input}};
endmodule
```

In this code, `{input}` after `WIDTH` means what? In what way that affects the parameter?

Comment: Consider asking here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: suggestion: do not use keywordsi (i.e., input) as variable names. It is confusing and some tools might choke on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curly brackets, preceded by the parameter, are called the *replication operator*.

```
assign result = {WIDTH{input}};
```

makes `WIDTH` copies of the 1-bit `input`-signal and assigns it to the WIDTH-bit output signal `result`. This means that `input` does thus not affect the parameter like you suspected in your question. Rather, the parameter affects how many copies of `input` are made.

For future reference please also consult [the SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595). Simple syntax-related questions like yours can be easily looked up in that document. For example, take a look at *Section 11.4.12.1 Replication operation* in the document that I referenced.